# Send message to mobile from PC c# aplication

Tags: c#, android, windows, mobile, console

I want to send a message to evry users who connect to the wireless. Actually, I want the user to receive a message on the device immediately after connecting to the wireless router. Never mind that the device in question, whether mobile or PC.

This means, when someone connects to my wireless router, I want that the user gets a message of welcome. I do not want to be the message SMS, and that I should not use the GSM network, but to appear as a AlertDialog or something.

I wonder if it is even possible to do, and it's not some kind of applications for Android, but if it is possible to do it without an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a multiplatform message service is almost virtualy impossible,and it requires you having knowledge of a wide number of arguments.On windows there was [net send](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx?mfr=true) available until windows xp,from xp on,you could try using [msg command line](http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/msg-command/),however this requires you having a program that interfaces itself with these programs to send your custom notifications.

As for android there are  [notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) but that requires the user having an app installed that listens to whenever he connects to the network,there are no other means of "sending" a message.Same story for iOs i suppose.

There can be an enormous number of configurations that a user could have that connects to your network,and having an interface that send a custom message for every platform would be a pretty crazy job.There can be Linux,Windows,Mac,not only but immagine all the versions those OS have,then there are all the mobile ones too,so i don't think a messaging or alert system is a viable way,as THERE ISN'T an universal way.

The best course of action is buying a router,or setting up yours,that whenever someone connects to your network and tries to navigate,they will be greeted with a custom page from your router,it is not hard to do,and there are a lot of routers that to that by nature.
Otherwise you could set up a custom gateway with [nocat](http://nocat.net/) OR even have a login system maybe,so you can have a log of every user that connects to your network

Comment: thank you for explaining how, why. Then I'll work out with this idea that you suggested.
Thank you again!